# Using Azure Notification Hub with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, azure-notificationhub

I want to build push notifications into my app using [Azure's Notification Hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj927170.aspx#BKMK_NH5). My app is built with HTML using Phonegap, so I'm wondering if anyone has seen a plugin or tools to make these work

Comment: Trying the same thing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221513/azure-notification-hub-registration-from-javascript-using-rest-services-fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please take a look at Windows Azure Notification Hubs plugin for Apache Cordova

https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub

This plugin support Windows8, Windows Phone8, iOS and Android platforms

Comment: tags are not supported so it's quite useless for me atm

Comment: It seems that the plugin is not maintained anymore. I get an error when installing the plugin on cordova 6.0

Comment: Did you try use any of forks?
https://github.com/craigomatic/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub
or
https://github.com/slimee/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub

Both seems to be maintained.

Comment: [self success:pluginResult callbackId:self.callbackId];
issue with this line. this plugin is not working now