# Azure Notification Hub registration from Javascript using REST services fails

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm trying to get a registration on the Azure Notification Hub working from html/javascript code running in a web view host (Phonegap / Intel XDK). There is no client library available, so I try to use the REST API (documentation: ).

I have the following Javascript code:

```
function registerWithAzureNotificationHub()
{
    var sas = "Endpoint=sb://eventpusher-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=69XuYoluyBKl6JkkN03Z1oNC7cFSZ4Ku0ZWmPuWoJzs=";
    var data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">\
        <content type="application/xml">\
        <MpnsRegistrationDescription xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">\
        <Tags>myTag, myOtherTag</Tags>\
        <ChannelUri>https://eventpusher-ns.servicebus.windows.net/eventpusher</ChannelUri>\
        </MpnsRegistrationDescription>\
        </content>\
    </entry>';
    if (AppMobi.iswp8) {
        window.alert("IS WP8");
    }
    else
    {
        window.alert("IS NOT WP8");
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "https://eventpusher-ns.servicebus.windows.net/EVENTPUSHER/registrations/?api-version=2013-08",
        contentType: "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": sas,
            "x-ms-version": "2013-08"
        },
        dataType: "xml",
        data: data,
        success: function(d) { window.alert("SUCCESS!"); },
        error: function(msg) { window.alert("FAILURE:" + JSON.stringify(msg)); }
    });
    window.alert("SENT!");
}
```

In the above case I use the Intel XDK with the code running on a WP8 device, so I register for MPNS (Microsoft Push Notification Service).

The above code fails, and returns without descriptive information about the cause of the error.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to register a mobile device for Azure Notification Hub from javascript code using REST services?
2. What could be wrong with the above code? Is the ChannelUri the correct Uri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible top use the REST interface from javascript.
In your code there are two main problems:

1. in the ChannelURI you should put the channelURI retrieved from the WindowsPhone HttpPushNotificationChannel (as in [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/notification-hubs/get-started-notification-hubs-wp8/) tutorial).
2. the authorization header is a token that is created for your specific request. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn170477.aspx)

A sample using WinJS is [available](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Service-Bus-Notification-3bfcd161). We will work on having a PhoneGap specific sample very soon!

Comment: Any news on the PhoneGap support for this?

Comment: Still no news on PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1):

I did post a server side snippet to register the device with token to the hub and to be able to send out the notification here :

[How to register devices to Azure Notification Hub from server side(with NodeJS sdk) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27033194/how-to-register-devices-to-azure-notification-hub-from-server-sidewith-nodejs-s/28178063#28178063)

I also have the client side code using ngCordova and PushPlugin in Ionic, let me know if anyone wants to see it.